# Cannot Subscript A PFObject Error

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfobject

I've attempted to solve this error, but I've had no luck in doing so. I'm getting the error: `Cannot subscript a value of type '[PFObject]' with an index of type 'String'` On this line of code: `self.postDates.append(posts["createdAt"] as! String)`.

This is the portion of code I'm having trouble with:

```
var posts : [Post] = []
var postDates = [String]()

func loadData() {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Post")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(posts: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?)-> Void in

        if error == nil {
            if let posts = posts {
                for post in posts {
                    self.postDates.append(posts["createdAt"] as! String)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } else {
            // is an error
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the date and then display it every time the user create  a new post utilizing Parse. Can anyone explain what is going on?

This is the tutorial I'm following along with: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3VQ0TE_fjU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `posts` is an array of `PFObject`, how can you get an element inside from `String`? It's supposed to be an `Int`. It's just your typo, you already knew what you are doing. `post` is the `PFObject` you want.

```
for post in posts {
    self.postDates.append(post["createdAt"] as! String)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get (and add) the created at date of the `PFObject`,
instead you are getting the date of and array of `PFObject` (Which Posts is).

You should try to get the elements in the array, and get the date from the element instead of the array.

```
for post in posts{
    postDates.append(post["createdAt"] as! String)
}
```